# OOP concept: is it possible to update the class of an instantiated object?

Tags: object-oriented, vb.net, inheritance

I am trying to write a simple program that should allow a user to save and display sets of heterogeneous, but somehow related data. For clarity sake, I will use a representative example of vehicles. The program flow is like this:

1. The program creates a **Garage** object, which is basically a class that can contain a list of vehicles objects
2. Then the users creates **Vehicles** objects, these **Vehicles** each have a property, lets say *License Plate Nr*. Once created, the **Vehicle** object get added to a list within the **Garage** object
3. --***Later on***--, the user can specify that a given **Vehicle** object is in fact a **Car** object or a **Truck** object (thus giving access to some specific attributes such as *Number of seats* for the Car, or *Cargo weight* for the truck)

At first sight, this might look like an OOP textbook question involving a base class and inheritance, but the problem is more subtle because at the object creation time (and until the user decides to give more info), the computer doesn't know the exact Vehicle type.

Hence my question: **how would you proceed to implement this program flow? Is OOP the way to go?**

Just to give an initial answer, here is what I've came up until now. There is only one Vehicle class and the various properties/values are handled by the main program (not the class) through a dictionary. However, I'm pretty sure that there must be a more elegant solution (I'm developing using VB.net):

```
Public Class Garage
    Public GarageAdress As String
    Private _ListGarageVehicles As New List(Of Vehicles)

    Public Sub AddVehicle(Vehicle As Vehicles)
        _ListGarageVehicles.Add(Vehicle)
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Vehicles
    Public LicensePlateNumber As String
    Public Enum VehicleTypes
        Generic = 0
        Car = 1
        Truck = 2
    End Enum
    Public VehicleType As VehicleTypes
    Public DictVehicleProperties As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
End Class
```

NOTE that in the example above the public/private modifiers do not necessarily reflect the original code

Comment: i suggest delegate pattern

Comment: Is there a reason you can't replace the object instance in the garage when you do learn the type?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there's no way to change the instantiated type of an object.  A `Vehicle` is a `Vehicle`, and will remain such until it goes out of scope.

Your choices here are threefold:

1. Make the type of `Vehicle` simply a property on the `Vehicle` object, and default it to `Unknown`.

   - This works best when there's little functional difference between a `Car` and a `Truck`.
   - Functions may return different results depending on the `VehicleType`, and you'll need to handle the `Unknown` case, but it's trivial to reassign.
2. Replace the `Vehicle` with a new object of `Car` or `Truck`

   - This would require either a `IsActuallyACar()` method on the `Vehicle` which returns a `Car`, or a `Car` constructor which takes a `Vehicle` as an argument *(which is the much better choice)*.
   - Going with this method requires you to manually remove the `Vehicle` from everywhere that it's stored, and replace it with the newly created object.
3. Rethink your design so that `Vehicle` is abstract and you don't create the object until you know what type it is.

   - This is probably the best option from an OO perspective.
   - You may need to temporarily store data in a non-`Vehicle` structure as you gather it, but you don't need to worry about changing the type later.

In your described scenario, I suspect #1 is the best choice.  Simply have logic which says "If the object has its type set to `Car`, then show this, if it's set to `Truck` show this."  It's not great OOP design, but it handles the "Vehicle of unknown type" the best.

Comment: Good answer.  I just wanted to point out that the reason you can't change the type is that storage is allocated based on the original type, so there may not be space available for any extra fields of the subclass.

Comment: Using a VehicleType property vice sub-classing has the benefit of preventing a potential explosion of subtypes. And thumbs-up on using an enum for the types, Federico.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't change the class of an object once instantiated, at least not in any programming language I know of. The reason is that this would blow up all sorts of guarantees a class hierarchy would otherwise give you; not to mention that "changing the class of an object" is a highly undefined requirement - how do you migrate the object's state? How do you map fields from one class to the other?

Considering your problem at hand; you have fallen prey to the seduction of naive polymorphism and reuse-by-inheritance. While both a `Car` and a `Truck` are vehicles, it is not very wise to have them inherit from `Vehicle` directly and encode all the behavior in these three classes. In other news, the textbook is wrong.

Instead, split the functionality into components. A `Vehicle` has a license plate, and a type. The type determines whether it is a car or a truck. You can then swap out the vehicle's type without changing its base properties.

Also, note that you are probably lying about your data. You create a `Vehicle` object without actually having a vehicle at hand; all you want is store the license plate number. So maybe putting the license plate into its own class, and linking it to an actual vehicle later might be a better design choice.

Comment: Python allows changing an object's type at runtime, although it's more a side-effect of the implementation than an actual, intended language feature.

Comment: Well, Python's classes are very loose anyway; you can monkey-patch methods and fields into existing objects, too, so the class doesn't really mean a lot. Changing the class is an intended feature in the sense that the intention is that you can change anything you bloody damn choose to.

Comment: CLOS does it too. And I disagree when you say that classes do not mean a lot if they can be changed at runtime.

Comment: @coredump: What I mean is that when an object can be monkey-patched, knowing what its class is doesn't give you any guarantees about the object itself, other than the constructor that was used to set up the object's initial state. In something like Java, knowing an object's class tells you which fields and methods it has, and which interfaces it implements. You can't do that in Python.

Comment: @tdammers: in practice, you have an idea of which class may or may not change dynamically and you can still access the information reliably at runtime; this is something you can do also in Java with class loaders and introspection. I agree you don't have static types but this is not necessarly a drawback.

Comment: @coredump: *you* have an idea; the computer does not, however, and more often than not, the idea is wrong in subtle ways.

Comment: @tdammers: also, lack of static types does not imply buggy code and crashes; when your program start manipulating data from unknown classes, you add runtime checks and exceptions. Regarding the original question, sometime it makes sense to change an object's class at runtime; it is one of the many solutions to the [Circle-Ellipse problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle-ellipse_problem#Change_the_programming_language).

Comment: Perl also allows to change an objects type.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a different design where garage contains a list of parkingspace objects.
The parkingspace object would implement the interface Licensplate.

Now I would have the vehicle object also implement the licensplate interface.

That way you can instantiate your list of parkingspaces, with corrensponding licenseplate numbers and instantiate your cars and trucks later with licensplates.

Answer (score 0):

probably you are looking for this pattern

you have to tweak this code to your exact requirement.

```
public interface IVehicle
{  
    string VehicleType{get;}
    int NumberOfSeets{set;get;}
    int Corgosize{set;get;}
}

public class Car:IVehicle
{
    private int _numseets;
    private int _corgo;
    public string VehicleType{
        get{return "CAR";}
    }

    public int NumberOfSeets
    { 
       get{return _numseets;}
       set{_numseets = value;}
    }

    public int Corgosize
    {
        get { return _corgo; }
        set { _corgo = value; }
    }
}

public class Truck : IVehicle
{
    private int _numseets;
    private int _corgo;
    public string VehicleType
    {
        get { return "Truck"; }
    }

    public int NumberOfSeets
    {
        get { return _numseets; }
        set { _numseets = value; }
    }

    public int Corgosize
    {
        get { return _corgo; }
        set { _corgo = value; }
    }
}

public class Vehicle : IVehicle
{
    private IVehicle _vehicle;
    public Vehicle(IVehicle refVehicle)
    {
        _vehicle = refVehicle;
    }
    public string VehicleType
    {
        get { return _vehicle.VehicleType; }
    }

    public int NumberOfSeets
    {
        get { return _vehicle.NumberOfSeets; }
        set {  }
    }

    public int Corgosize
    {
        get { return _vehicle.Corgosize; }
        set {  }
    }

}

public class MainClass
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Vehicle car, truck;
        car = new Vehicle(new Car());
        truck = new Vehicle(new Truck());
        Console.WriteLine("Car type ->{0}",car.VehicleType);
        Console.WriteLine("truck type ->{0}", truck.VehicleType);
        Console.ReadKey();

    }

}
```